# docker-compose execute volume script as root

Tags: docker, centos, docker-compose, percona

I have such docker-compose.yml f.e.:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    #build: db
    image: percona:5.7.24-centos
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bc
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and the script is f.e.:

`mkdir /home/workdirectory/`

There is no `sudo` in that image.

Default user is `mysql`.

Initial place is just `/`.

So how can I execute scripts inside `./db` as a root on that image?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit your own docker image from `percona:5.7.24-centos` and switch user or install `sudo`. Or just create necessary directories in `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the following **assuming** your script is a bash script and it's **placed** inside the `db` folder:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /home/workdirectory/some-sub-folder/
```

then make sure your container is up and running by executing `docker-compose up -d`

then use the following command to execute some script from inside the container:

`docker exec db /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sh`

Link:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/